# Windows 10 Webstore apps, how do I run them in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch

I have downloaded an app on the Microsoft webstore named Trello.

Because this app has no directory or .exe what I can find I am struggling to work out the right command I need to use in the batch file in order to run / start up this program in my batch file?

Does anyone know how I would do this?

I managed to find it in: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\45273LiamForsyth.PawsforTrello_2.11.4.0_x64__7pb5ddty8z1pa\app\Trello.exe but running with or without administrator mode it comes up with:

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot run apps from the commandline. The app must create support for it. For example Windows Terminal created support for it by creating a wt.exe that you can run from the commandline.

Comment: @LPChip, try the work-around below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [open a Windows Store ("Metro style") app by having Windows *Explorer* do it for you](https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/57000-method-open-any-windows-10-apps-command-line.html):

1. In *Explorer*, in the location bar, enter `shell:AppsFolder`.
2. Browse to the location of the app, e.g. *Snip & Sketch*. [On my PC, it took some time for all applications and apps to be fully displayed.]
3. Right-click on the shortcut, drag to the Desktop, and select `Create link in Desktop`.
4. Right-click the new link and select *Properties*.
5. Open *Notepad*, enter `explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\`, append the *Target* shown in the *Properties* dialog, and append to that `!App`. In the case of *Snip & Sketch*, the text in *Notepad* should be:

   `start explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App`
6. Save the file with extension `.bat`.

Note the character before App is exclamation point (bang).