# Add snip & sketch to windows context menu

Tags: windows, windows-registry, regedit

What I want is to right click on a `.png` file and edit it with "Snip & Sketch" app. I know it can be done via the `Open with` sub-menu, but I would like to have it pinned to the top of context menu (below open)

[image]

I followed [this tutorial](https://abcmemo.com/2016/08/16/add-an-application-shortcut-to-windows-file-explorers-context-menu/) of how to add it to register editor.

I found the way launch the app via CMD [in this post](https://superuser.com/a/1540123).

I tried to do this fo a `.png` file:

[image]

`pngfile`

[image]

I tried a few methods. None of them worked.

- `explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App %1`
- `C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App %1`
- `"C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe" "shell:appsFolder\\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" "%1"`

Finally I rebooted my PC. I have not had any luck thus far. Any tips?

Comment: In Windows 10 and Windows 11, right click on PNG file and "Open With" already includes the Snip 'n Sketch App.

Comment: Yes, I included that picture in my original post. Quoting myself  "I know it can be done via the Open with sub-menu, but I would like to have it pinned to the top of context menu"

Comment: Gray on black is difficult to see. I do not change sort orders on Open With or any other context because (a) it does not add time to my day and (b) it is prone to error.

Comment: True that is not add much time, but I'm meticulous

Comment: [How to Add “Edit with Snip & Sketch” Option to Right-Click Menu](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/edit-with-snip-sketch-right-click-menu/)

Comment: Thanks @w32sh . Worked like a charm 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by **@w32sh** above, I got it to the context menu.

Direct `.reg` modification file can be **[downloaded here](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/snip-sketch-context-menu.zip)**

> - Double-click the enclosed registry file “snip-sketch-context-menu.reg“
> - Click Yes when asked for confirmation.

[Source](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/edit-with-snip-sketch-right-click-menu/)

### Contents of snip-sketch-context-menu.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;Add "Edit with Snip & Sketch" to the right-click menu in Windows 10/11

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\Sketch]
"ActivatableClassId"="App.AppX99naa8pv4a8nkjghzyt7drksgwxwbtsg.mca"
"PackageId"="Microsoft.ScreenSketch_10.2008.2277.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe"
"ContractId"="Windows.File"
"DesiredInitialViewState"=dword:00000000
@="Edit with Snip && Sketch"
"Added by Winhelponline"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\Sketch\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{4ED3A719-CEA8-4BD9-910D-E252F997AFC2}",
```